# how to make mapbox digital style

Tags: styles, customization, mapbox

Im new in mapbox development.

Can somebody help me how to make map style like that:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That image is a reference to Studio's X-Ray view, which appears when you click the `Select data` tab of Mapbox Studio's `+ Add Layer` button: [here's a quick screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReFI8.png)

Every element of your map style is customizable, so there's nothing to prevent you from modifying all of your elements to replicate this look. This tutorial walks you through the basics: https://www.mapbox.com/help/create-a-custom-style/

If you want to get up and running more quickly, you can always copy one of Mapbox's designer styles to your account: https://www.mapbox.com/designer-maps/